# Таблица MS Word

Tags: ms-word

Есть обычная таблица в Word, в ней есть элемент управления содержимым "поле со списком" с выбором продукта, кроме этого в таблице есть столбцы с ценой продукта. Как реализовать подстановку цены продукта к определенному товару? И возможно ли вообще сделать это через Word?